# What does getint (int *) mean?

Tags: c, function

```
getint (int *);
```

I am not really sure what does `getint (int *)` mean? Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a function prototype declaring the function `getint()`. The function takes as pointer to an `int` as a parameter.

When prototyping a function it is not necessary to specify the parameters' names.

The prototype is missing a return type, which for C then defaults to `int`. Omiting a return type however is violating the recent C standard, so code doing so could be considered invalid.

An equivalent to

```
getint(int *);
```

though would be

```
int getint(int * pi);
```

Comment: there is no difference between this two instructions?

Comment: Note that implicit int rule has been removed since C99. So it's not a valid prototype.

Comment: @BlueMoon Even when using GCC in C89 mode you get a warning when the return type is missing.

Comment: @aik sir, good morning. the parameter name is optional though, am I right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Correct, a function's prototype does not need to specifiy the parameters' names (if any).

Comment: @user3826752 there's no instruction here. Nothing called instruction in C either. They're statements

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** `getint (int *);` is a forward declaration for a function, in a *very bad* programming style. Without any explicit return type, it will default to `int`.

The recommended way to write is is to specify the return type explicitly, like

- if `int`, like

  ```
  int getint(int *);  //yes, omitting the identifier name is correct, see note below
  ```

  or,

  ```
  int getint(int * outVar);    //we can have the name, if we want.
  ```
- if `void`, like

  ```
  void getint(int *);
  ```

  or,

  ```
  void getint(int * outVar);
  ```

or any return type you want.

---

NOTE:

Just for further reference, from `C11`, chapter §6.7.6.3, *Function declarators*, (emphasis mine)

> If, in the declaration `'T D1'`, `D1` has the form
>
> ```
> D( parameter-type-list )
> ```
>
> ...
>
> A parameter type list **specifies the types of, and may declare identifiers** for, the parameters of the function.

So, the identifier name is optional.

Comment: Or even better, using a descriptive formal parameter as well: `int getint(int *result)`.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom _maybe_ better, but not **required**, however, updated my answer. :-)

Comment: "*if `int` ...*": `getint()` as per the OP **is** returning `int` (or should be considered as invalid, due to the missing return type) .

Comment: @alk as it looks like we already have the result through the argument passed, it can be defined as `void` also, right?

Comment: The return-type could be defined as anything ;-), but it **is** defined as `int`, as it isn't specificied at all.

Comment: @alk yes, that's the _default_. I'll update my answer accordingly to avoid any possible confusion. Thank you sir for reviewing my answer, though.

Comment: @alk so how do you suggest I can improve the words used? Please let me know or feel free to edit my answer. :-)

Comment: It's fine now ... :-)

Comment: @alk  Yay !! That means I'm improving my English vocabulary. Thanks again. :-)

Comment: I wasn't a argueing about your english, btw ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The code is not valid C. If it compiles, consider upgrading to a compiler which is not older than 15 years.

History lesson:

In older, obsolete versions of the C standard you were allowed to omit the return type when writing a function declaration, in which case `getint(int *);` would mean the same thing as `int getint(int *);`, because if you specified no return type it would default to `int`. It was however bad practice to do so even back in 1990.